# How to convert "1030" to 10-30 in mm-dd date format in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Is there a simple way to convert numbers like 1030, 0131, 1231, etc to an mm-dd (or even mm-dd-yyyy assuming everything is 2020) format, so that I can perform date calculations with them? For example, I would like to be able to do (1231 minus 0131) = 11 months.

Of course, I could just do the following to change the formatting, but looking to see if there's a more intuitive way!

```
startDate = startDate[:2] + "-" + startDate[2:] + "-2020"
endDate = endDate[:2] + "-" + endDate[2:] + "-2020"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "date calculations"? Note that a duration in month is ambiguous - different months do not have equal number of days

Comment: @MrFuppes was rounding there, I meant for the calculation to be in days. So this would be 335 days

Comment: Since you're asking for a 'more intuitive' version of something that works, this appears to be an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to [datetime object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) straight away, using `strptime` directive `"%m%d"`. This allows you to make [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) calculations later on. The default year is 1900; if you wish, you can replace by 2020.

```
from datetime import datetime

startDate, endDate = "0131", "1231"

startDate, endDate = (datetime.strptime(startDate, "%m%d").replace(year=2020), 
                      datetime.strptime(endDate,"%m%d").replace(year=2020))

deltaDays = (endDate-startDate).days
# 335
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if it is not exactly what you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "1030"
d = '-'.join([s[:2], s[2:]]) + '-2020'
date_object = datetime.strptime(d, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! That's what I am currently doing. Was just wondering if there was a simpler way to accomplish this. I'll mark this as the right answer if no one else responds